# How to bind element to background-image (responsive)?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to bind (HTML) elements to a background image of a parent element?
In the following example code, I want the (hover) elements to always stay on the blocks, even when the window is resized to a small (mobile) sized screen.

```css
.steps {
  background: url(https://i.gyazo.com/c027c7cefa8f66fb10135547ac650d24.png) center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 95px;
}
.steps ul {
  /* margin-top: 0; */
  /* margin-left: -246px; */
  margin-left: -286px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  margin-top: 13px;
  position: absolute;
}
.steps ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.steps ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 82px;
  width: 116px;
  /*margin-bottom: 22px;*/
  text-indent: -9999em;
}
.steps ul li a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="steps">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Block 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Block 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Block 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Block 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kcvukkpm/)

The problem that occurs now is that the blocks won't stay in-line. I thought of putting a parent container element around all this but that will cause the image won't be centered then anymore.

Could anyone give me any advice on this?

Comment: it would be easier to manipulate with it if you set separate image/background for each step.. not like this in one image

Comment: @jakob You are right about that and I agree it would be easier to manipulate this kind of stuff that way (and it would be most suitable/properly  to do it like that). The problem is that I only have this background-image and should be able to work with that. Somehow in some old piece of code it seems to be working fine, but putting things in Bootstrap I have to make use of different screen widths, meaning I have to reposition a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I notice you are using:

position: absolute;

Absolute positioning is not a technique suitable for responsive design.  With responsive design, you would usually use relative size units such as ems, and use relative positioning techniques instead of absolute.  I would say you need to rethink your design technique to use relative size and relative positioning.

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer to the issue (or question).